# Why is phase lost in x-ray crystallography?

Tags: phase

everywhere says that phase is los but WHY?
it is that when we measure x rays we cannot measure phase?
is it that phase is lost because of such high scattering?
what is the REASON for the phase lose in x-ray crystallography and NOT in cryoEM
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Diffraction causes the outbound wave to be something like a Fourier transform of the specimen's spatial scattering density.

The problem arises because our available x-ray detectors only capture the intensity of the x-rays by essentially counting photons. [We have no detectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_problem) that are fast enough to record the wave nature (and thus phase) of x-rays due to their extremely high frequency.

This is in contrast to radio frequency radiation, where our current electronic detectors can directly measure the waveform of the electromagnetic field rising and falling.

For higher frequency radiation like optical or x-rays one can play some tricks with analog interference, to convert the phase information into an amplitude pattern which can be recorded with available detectors and which then allows to extract both phase and amplitude information.

For x-rays one can use [ptychography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptychography), to allow phase reconstruction, however, one still cannot image anything with even close to the wavelength of hard x-ray radiation because it is (at least currently) impossible to manufacture reference apertures that are as small as the wavelength of hard x-ray.